# Get HEX value from farbtastic color picker and add it to html tag attribute

Tags: jquery, html, attr, color-picker

So, what I would like to do is:

I have color-picker "farbtastic" which works great. Later in code I have "img" element with attribute from another plugin for image manipulation. I would like to set farbtastic HEX value like an attribute to this img tag. I tried following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var picker = $.farbtastic('#picker');
        picker.linkTo(function onColorChange(color) {
        $('filter-tint').attr('data-pb-tint-colour',color)
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And this is my img tag:

```
    <img id="filter-tint" class="filter-tint" src="img/barva.png" data-pb-tint-opacity="1" data-pb-tint-colour="#ffffff"/>
```

Please help, I've tried passing this value for days now, but with no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `#` for the ID selector:

```
$('filter-tint').attr('data-pb-tint-colour',color)
// ^----
```

Comment: Fixed that one, but still - nothing happens. I don't have DOM error, img tag stays the same at it was, document loads, image has a color of #ffffff with no change.

Comment: @marc_s Do you use _View Source_ or a debugging tool like firebug?

Comment: I use Firebug and Chrome's integrated "console". My problem just got away right now. There was obviously something with this "special attributes" for img tag. Now I'm just using background-color style attribute and it works like a charm :) Thank you all. Solved.